# What is the difference between `java -version` and `java -showversion`?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments, jvm-hotspot

What is the difference between `java -version` and `java -showversion` ?

[This blog](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/useful-jvm-flags-part-1-jvm-types-and-compiler-modes/) says

> The -version flag terminates the JVM immediately after printing out
>   the above data. However, there is a similar flag -showversion which
>   can be used to produce the same output but then proceed and execute a
>   given Java application.

So I ran a Java program in one tab in my terminal. (I use Ubuntu)
And in another tab, while the program was still running, I gave `java -version` . As per the above statement given in the blog, I expected my Java program to quit, but it didnt. 
Also, when i ran `java -showversion` , it gave exactly the same output and the program execution didnt terminate.

So what is the difference between the two ?

I use Java 8 and this was the output :

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

Note : The blog uses Java 6. So has something changed in later versions of Java ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call `java -showVersion MyProgram` and it will run MyProgram.class after displaying the version.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about basic Unix usage. You were starting *a completely separate copy* of the JVM, which will have absolutely nothing to do with a copy running somewhere else.

Comment: It's not really a Unix specific thing @chrylis.  That's the way it works on every OS I've ever seen

Comment: @JJF Yes, but it's much less typical to be launching program instances from a multi-tab terminal on Windows.

Comment: Your question is answered fully by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html). Hard to understand why you're wasting time here when you could have answered your own question in about 20 seconds.

Comment: Tabbed shell has nothing to do with the behavior he's seeing.

Comment: @JJF Make up your mind. Tabbed shell implies that he is starting another process, which is what your own answer says.

Answer (score 2):

As per [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)

-showversion

> Displays version information and continues execution of the
>   application. This option is equivalent to the -version option except
>   that the latter instructs the JVM to exit after displaying version
>   information.

-version

> Displays version information and then exits. This option is
>   equivalent to the -showversion option except that the latter does not
>   instruct the JVM to exit after displaying version information.

Comment: @EJP The problem at hand is about *invoking a separate JVM launch* and why it doesn't terminate an existing JVM. This does not address the issue.

Answer (score -3):

When you run your program it creates a process.  That process is independent of the second process you create when you run 'java -version' in another shell.
The first process is unaffected by anything that the second process does.